# Applying "file" linux command to binary buffer in Perl

Tags: linux, image, perl, file, raw-data

I have image in buffer after retrieving it from the Web:

```
my $img = $webapi->get('http://myserver.com/image/123423.jpg');
```

After the call, raw data is in the $img. I want to make sure the data represents image and not text, so I save it to a file on disk and run file command:

```
open my $fh, '>', '/tmp/images/rawdata.bin';
print $fh $img;
close $fh;
$res = `file /tmp/images/rawdata.bin`;
if ($res =~ 'GIF|JPEG|PNG') print "Image";
else "Not image";
```

How do I avoid saving raw data to file and do the work in memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`file` can read data from `STDIN`. So the easiest way might be:

```
open ( my $file_cmd, '|-', 'file -' ) or die $!;
print {$file_cmd} $img;
print <$file_cmd>;
```

There appears to be a module - `File::Type` which does this. My quick testing implies it's not as smart as `file` making it somewhat less useful.

Comment: Not sure, but also seems geared up to MIME types, where `file` does mor .

Comment: Are you referring to the direction of the pipe symbol? Because I'm pretty sure that's the right way around. (opening as `-|` means I can't then `print` to it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach: A Jpeg start with \xFF \xD8, GIFs start with "GIF89a" or "GIF87a" and PNGs start with these decimals: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10.

Comment: You've also got `/usr/share/misc/magic` you can refer to on *nix systems. Which is what `file` does.